# regex combining groups into one string

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

so here is a string

```
[{'display_html': "<img src='/images/C_small.png'/> <b><a href='/u/11339405'>GDcheerios</a></b> achieved rank #936 on <a href='/b/1952051?m=0'>frederic - ONLYWONDER [Singing sometimes]</a> (osu!)", 'beatmap_id': 1952051, 'beatmapset_id': '807885', 'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 1, 5, 17, 11, 80000), 'library': '', 'epic_factor': '1'}, {'display_html': "<img src='/images/A_small.png'/> <b><a href='/u/11339405'>GDcheerios</a></b> achieved rank #77 on <a href='/b/2401143?m=0'>Falcom Sound Team jdk - Desert After Tears [Inferno]</a> (osu!)", 'beatmap_id': 2401143, 'beatmapset_id': '1150262', 'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 1, 4, 21, 3, 80000), 'library': '', 'epic_factor': '1'}]
```

and I have some regex code to get certain parts out of it that I want

```
\>(\w+)|( achieved rank .\w+ on )|m=0'>(.*? - .*?\])
```

[image]

the problem is that they are each store in their own group. So when I goto print the .group() it just results in

> GDcheerios

and what I want is

> GDcheerios achieved rank #936 on frederic - ONLYWONDER [Singing sometimes]

Comment: You need to remove html tags ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `BeautifulSoup` to parse html

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime

data = [{'display_html': "<img src='/images/C_small.png'/> <b><a href='/u/11339405'>GDcheerios</a></b> achieved rank #936 on <a href='/b/1952051?m=0'>frederic - ONLYWONDER [Singing sometimes]</a> (osu!)", 'beatmap_id': 1952051, 'beatmapset_id': '807885', 'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 1, 5, 17, 11, 80000), 'library': '', 'epic_factor': '1'}, {'display_html': "<img src='/images/A_small.png'/> <b><a href='/u/11339405'>GDcheerios</a></b> achieved rank #77 on <a href='/b/2401143?m=0'>Falcom Sound Team jdk - Desert After Tears [Inferno]</a> (osu!)", 'beatmap_id': 2401143, 'beatmapset_id': '1150262', 'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 1, 4, 21, 3, 80000), 'library': '', 'epic_factor': '1'}]

for i in data:
    s = BeautifulSoup(i['display_html'], 'html.parser')
    print(s.text)
```

**Output:**

```
 GDcheerios achieved rank #936 on frederic - ONLYWONDER [Singing sometimes] (osu!)
 GDcheerios achieved rank #77 on Falcom Sound Team jdk - Desert After Tears [Inferno] (osu!)
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of `findall`. Probably not the most elegant, but it works:

```py
import re

target_string = r"[{'display_html': \"<img src='/images/C_small.png'/> <b><a href='/u/11339405'>GDcheerios</a></b> achieved rank #936 on <a href='/b/1952051?m=0'>frederic - ONLYWONDER [Singing sometimes]</a> (osu!)\", 'beatmap_id': 1952051, 'beatmapset_id': '807885', 'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 1, 5, 17, 11, 80000), 'library': '', 'epic_factor': '1'}, {'display_html': \"<img src='/images/A_small.png'/> <b><a href='/u/11339405'>GDcheerios</a></b> achieved rank #77 on <a href='/b/2401143?m=0'>Falcom Sound Team jdk - Desert After Tears [Inferno]</a> (osu!)\", 'beatmap_id': 2401143, 'beatmapset_id': '1150262', 'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 1, 4, 21, 3, 80000), 'library': '', 'epic_factor': '1'}]"

result = re.findall(r"\>(\w+)|( achieved rank .\w+ on )|m=0'>(.*? - .*?\])", target_string)

for i in range(2):
    print(result[i*3][0] + result[i*3+1][1] + result[i*3+2][2])
```

output:

```
GDcheerios achieved rank #936 on frederic - ONLYWONDER [Singing sometimes]
GDcheerios achieved rank #77 on Falcom Sound Team jdk - Desert After Tears [Inferno]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a single expression from the above regex. That will return a tuple with all of the matches, which you can than quickly combine using `''.join`. The only thing you have to do for that is replace the pipe (`|`) by `.+`.

```
html = """
[{'display_html': "<img src='/images/C_small.png'/> <b><a href='/u/11339405'>GDcheerios</a></b> achieved rank #936 on <a href='/b/1952051?m=0'>frederic - ONLYWONDER [Singing sometimes]</a> (osu!)", 'beatmap_id': 1952051, 'beatmapset_id': '807885', 'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 1, 5, 17, 11, 80000), 'library': '', 'epic_factor': '1'}, {'display_html': "<img src='/images/A_small.png'/> <b><a href='/u/11339405'>GDcheerios</a></b> achieved rank #77 on <a href='/b/2401143?m=0'>Falcom Sound Team jdk - Desert After Tears [Inferno]</a> (osu!)", 'beatmap_id': 2401143, 'beatmapset_id': '1150262', 'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 1, 4, 21, 3, 80000), 'library': '', 'epic_factor': '1'}]
[{'display_html': "<img src='/images/C_small.png'/> <b><a href='/u/11339405'>GDcheerios</a></b> achieved rank #936 on <a href='/b/1952051?m=0'>frederic - ONLYWONDER [Singing sometimes]</a> (osu!)", 'beatmap_id': 1952051, 'beatmapset_id': '807885', 'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 1, 5, 17, 11, 80000), 'library': '', 'epic_factor': '1'}, {'display_html': "<img src='/images/A_small.png'/> <b><a href='/u/11339405'>GDcheerios</a></b> achieved rank #77 on <a href='/b/2401143?m=0'>Falcom Sound Team jdk - Desert After Tears [Inferno]</a> (osu!)", 'beatmap_id': 2401143, 'beatmapset_id': '1150262', 'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 1, 4, 21, 3, 80000), 'library': '', 'epic_factor': '1'}]
"""
result = re.findall(r"\>(\w+).+( achieved rank .\w+ on ).+m=0'>(.*? - .*?\])", html)

for each in result:
    print(''.join(each))
```

Output:

```
GDcheerios achieved rank #77 on Falcom Sound Team jdk - Desert After Tears [Inferno]
GDcheerios achieved rank #77 on Falcom Sound Team jdk - Desert After Tears [Inferno]
```